# Error when converting datatable to json

Tags: c#, json, winforms

When converting datatable of each rows into json , I am not getting proper format and also getting  error `"RowError":"","RowState":2`

Here is my code:

```
 StrQry="select * from doctor_mas where version_code=1";
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        dt=Sqlhelper.OleDbTable(StrQry);


        try
        {
            for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
             string JSONresult;
             JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt.Rows[i]);
             var Update = new Salestrak.Update.updDoc();
             String Authrized = Update.updateTable((int)dt.Rows[i][0], "doctor_mas", JSONresult); 
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sync Aborted");
        }
```

Resulted Json string is:

```
{"RowError":"","RowState":2,"Table":[{"id":248.0,"birth_date":"1950-01-01T00:00:00","doctor_code":"D248","doctor_name":"Ajay A Haryani","version_code":1},{"id":293.0,"birth_date":"1990-05-26T00:00:00","doctor_code":"D293","doctor_name":"Aarti  Thakker","version_code":1}],"ItemArray":[248.0,"1950-01-01T00:00:00","D248","Ajay A Haryani",0,1.0,2.0,"Sandip Palekar","Mumbai-2",2.0,"Vasudhan,1],"HasErrors":false}
```

Comment: Please include enough information so this can be re-created, And don't shout: it won't get help any quicker,

Comment: your `json` includes all the properties of  a `DataRow`.Can you explain what specific need do you have?

Comment: `{"id":293.0,"birth_date":"1990-05-26T00:00:00","doctor_code":"D293","doctor_name":"Aarti  Thakker","version_code":1}` i just want ths much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray);
```

Basically you want to serialize the array of contents of the `DataRow`.

An alternative with some overhead -

```
var o = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt.Rows[0]);

for (var i = 0; i < JObject.Parse(o)["Table"].Count(); i++)
{
    var t = JObject.Parse(o)["Table"][i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [suresh's blog](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/05/c-convert-datatable-to-json-string-in-c.html)

```
// This method is used to convert datatable to json string
public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SureshDasari;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=true"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select title=City,lat=latitude,lng=longitude,description from LocationDetails", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }
    }
}
```